# Moderator comment on disputed flag: is that for me or the original flagger?

Tags: support, flags, disputed-flags

I see the following on my flag history:

> invalid flag – 23 hours ago   disputed - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

It refers to a flag on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513175/long-underline-tag-not-u/15513219#15513219). Now, if I'm not mistaken I flagged another flag as invalid. If that's really the case, should I really be seeing the moderator message? Isn't it addressed to the user who raised the original flag? I'm confused...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that message is addressed to the other user.  When there are multiple flags on the same answer, moderators cannot clear the flags separately. We have to dismiss them all with a single action.  It's probably better in this case to send you both the "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies..." message, since the only other option is to mark the flags as helpful and have no message sent at all to the person who threw the first flag.  You knew about the first flag, so it's better to send you a message that you need to ignore than it is to *not* send a message to someone who's flagging incorrectly.

Also, the flag is marked "disputed" in your flag history, not "declined" so it shouldn't have any effect at all on your flagging score.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I actually was in doubt if I had raised the original flag, or disputed it. I failed to notice that "invalid flag" at the beginning of the message explained what *my* flag was. I focused on the mod message too much.